# Logstash grok for special character

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Following is my log

```
# Time: 2017-11-02T07:41:22.631956Z# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:
```

I am not able to write grok pattern for the word `root[root]`.
I want this value as a single column. Example : `host = root[root]`.

I want `[` in my value.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%{DATA:user}` should do.

You can see the definition for DATA [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns#L14).

A grok filter for parsing your whole logline could look somewhat like this (I'm not really sure which parts you're interested in but you get the idea):

```
# Time: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}# %{DATA:user}@%{DATA:host}: %{DATA:user2} @ %{DATA:host2} \[\]  Id:
```

Results from https://grokconstructor.appspot.com:
[image]